# Is Ubuntu Desktop free for a business solution?

Tags: legal

Is [Ubuntu Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Variants) free for business platforms?

Has Ubuntu changed its conditions about using the OS for profit purposes?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "for business platforms". Do you mean to run Ubuntu inside your business or do you mean to sell Ubuntu on systems? Or perhaps you mean you want to build applications on top of Ubuntu?

Comment: of course, for using it, and also to build applications on top of Ubuntu

Comment: What software do you normally use?  Some have versions that run on linux, or alternatives, but Windows software often will not run on an Ubuntu machine (certainly not without time and effort).  If you were to give us an idea of what your business does we will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is free (as in no cost) and free (as in open source), but you can [purchase support](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/overview) if you need it from Canonical.

You can find out more about the [philosophy](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy) and more about [why it is free](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/why-is-it-free).

It is free to use as a business and free to develop products on.

Information about [Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/overview).

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/why-is-it-free

Comment: With the paid for support option you do also get a management solution called Landscape

Comment: I added information about landscape to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

From [**Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/) we were able to read the following in 2012:

> **Why is it free?**
>   Our global community is made up of thousands of people who want to help build the best open-source operating system in the world. They share their time and skills to make sure that Ubuntu keeps getting better and better. From IBM to Google, Firefox to Wikipedia – some of today's best software is based on an open-source model. Shared efforts. Shared principles. No cost.

There also is a page [**Ubuntu - Our Mission**](https://www.ubuntu.com/community/mission) where you find details on Open Source and why Ubuntu is free to use:

> Quoting the Free Software Foundation's, ['What is Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html),' the freedoms at the core of free software are defined as:
>
> - The freedom to run the program, for any purpose.
> - The freedom to study how the program works and adapt it to your needs.
> - The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help others.
> - The freedom to improve the program and release your improvements to the public, so that everyone benefits.

When using Ubuntu in your company you may also be interested in the [Ubuntu Licensing Policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/licensing) and in additional paid services from the [Ubuntu Advantage](https://www.ubuntu.com/support/plans-and-pricing) suite.

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not. Ubuntu is free as in "costing no money" to use for the default software (there is 3rd party software that can cost money). The only thing Ubuntu costs is the time you invest in getting to learn how it works.

Depending on how large your organization is it might be worth it to get some paid support with [Ubuntu Advantage](http://www.ubuntu.com/management).

> Ubuntu Advantage is the commercial support package from Canonical. It includes Landscape, the Ubuntu systems management tool, for running desktop, server and public cloud deployments, or building and managing private OpenStack clouds.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about it. It is absolutely [free](https://ubuntu.com/community/mission), but you can [contact Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/contact-us) for paid technical [support](https://ubuntu.com/support). Still, you will get [community support](https://ubuntu.com/support/community-support) absolutely free.

**For more details**

1. [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/server)
2. [Ubuntu in organisations](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/organisations)